# Expression return weird error

Tags: haxe

I'm trying to use an expression block:

```
var branches = [for (branchName in process.toString().split("\n")) {
    {label: branchName};
}];

Vscode.window.showQuickPick(branches); // <-- this line 25, 26 is empty line
```

but I get:

```
/src/Main.hx:26: characters 8-35 : Constraint check failure for showQuickPick.T
/src/Main.hx:26: characters 8-35 : { label : String } should be vscode.QuickPickItem
/src/Main.hx:26: characters 8-35 : { label : String } should be { label : String, ?detail : Null<String>, description : String }
/src/Main.hx:26: characters 8-35 : { label : String } has no field description
```

Expression block does not allow to return an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line outlines the problem:

```
/src/Main.hx:26: characters 8-35 : { label : String } has no field description
```

Your object needs a String `description` field, as that field is not optional.

See: https://github.com/vshaxe/vscode-extern/blob/master/src/vscode/QuickPickItem.hx